# Object leaked: Object allocated and stored is not referenced later in this execution

Tags: objective-c, ios, memory-leaks

After using the analyze tool, I am getting the following warning "Object leaked: Object allocated and stored is not referenced later in this execution"

[image]

How can I remove this warning?

Comment: Please don't use screenshots of code; that just makes it hard to read. At least take the time to copy-paste it. You can indicate the line on which you're getting the notice with a comment.

Comment: I think OP used screenshots to show arrows as they are some strange things to a person who sees them first ever in his life. And screenshot in this question was useful for me to make me sure we are facing the same problem.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Inside the IF block you reassign your UIWebView without EVER having used the initial assignment. Instead have something like this...

```
UIWebView *videoView = nil;

if([self.webViewCache objectForKey:cellId]) {
    videoView = .....normal code here
} else {
    videoView = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 104, 104)];
    .... normal code here
}
```

Comment: This is my preferred solution, not the only one, but the tidiest.

Answer (score 2):

It's because you allocate your

```
UIWebView* videoView = [UIWebview alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 104, 104)];
```

but then in your if statement, you assign this videoView with something else, hence you're losing pointer to the initial allocated object.

Change your declaration to

```
UIWebView* videoView = nil;
```

then in your else

```
videoView = [UIWebview alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 104, 104)];
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to release previous object referenced by videoView, before assigning a new value.